# The selector "ng-component" did not match any elements running Angular 8 example

Tags: angular8

I am working on the following example:

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-wtpacb)

I am getting a run-time error:

```
Error: The selector "ng-component" did not match any elements
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to disappear when you remove `home.module.ts` which isn't even used by the application. I'm not sure why you get this message, but you should either remove `home.module.ts`, or reference to `home.component.ts` only in the `home.module.ts` and remove that declaration from `app.module.ts`

Comment: Check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-wtpacb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.module.ts

Comment: Not sure I understand your example. It has same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you your own link. Here's my fork https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-7mmzdv